# unit tests crashing in python 2.6 (i'm using Travis CI)

Tags: python, unit-testing, crash, python-2.6

This is the crash:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 22, in
>   
>       test_suite = "tests.get_tests",   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
>       dist.run_commands()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py",
>   line 138, in run
>       self.with_project_on_sys_path(self.run_tests)   File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py",
>   line 118, in with_project_on_sys_path
>       func()   File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py",
>   line 164, in run_tests
>       testLoader = cks   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 816, in **init**
>       self.parseArgs(argv)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 843, in parseArgs
>       self.createTests()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 849, in createTests
>       self.module)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 613, in loadTestsFromNames
>       suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 598, in loadTestsFromName
>       test = obj()   File "/home/travis/build/myproject/foo/tests/**init**.py", line 7, in
>   get_tests
>       return unittest.TestLoader().discover(start_dir, pattern="test_*.py") AttributeError: 'TestLoader' object has no
>   attribute 'discover'

this is my tests/**init**.py

```
import os.path
import unittest


def get_tests():
    start_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return unittest.TestLoader().discover(start_dir, pattern="test_*.py")
```

in python 2.7, pypy, 3.2, 3.3 works correctly

why is crashing on python 2.6? thanks!

Comment: http://owlsayswoot.therandomist.com/2010/07/24/how-to-run-all-the-python-unit-tests-in-a-directory/
python2.6 hasn't the discover method, how can i do this "if" in the code for get_test on python -2.7 and +2.7? thanks

Comment: It crashes since `discover` method is introduced in python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
from discover import DiscoveringTestLoader


def get_tests():
    start_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    test_loader = DiscoveringTestLoader()
    return test_loader.discover(start_dir, pattern="test_*.py")
```

install with: `pip install discover`